# margin-top isn't calculated as expected

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I try to center a `div` on my page. It should use just relative values, so its size depends just on the window size.
I found a solution and it centers the box, but it seems that the margin isn't calculated correctly. Instead the size of the `body` gets bigger then the window. In the following example firebug tells me that the box `#container` has size 1265x335 on my screen. When inspecting `#content` its size is 506x134 and 2px boarder on each side, which matches my calculation. But the top margin is 316.

Have I got something wrong?
The margin should be 25% of 335, right?
How can I fix this?

Here's the HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      nothing...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here the CSS:

```css
html {
  height:            100%;
}

body {
  height:            100%;
  margin:            0em 0em 0em 0em;
}

#container {
  height:            100%;
}

#content {
  text-align:        center;
  width:             40%;
  height:            40%;
  margin-top:        25%;
  margin-left:       auto;
  margin-right:      auto;
  margin-bottom:     auto;
  border:            2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the **width** of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.

So you get 25% of 1265 which explains the behavior you are seeing. Unfortunately, I don't have any solutions to offer.

**Edit**: CSS3 makes this statement dependent on whether the containing block is [horizontal](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#horizontal) (you would want it to be vertical). I don't think that any browsers implement the required `block-progression` property however (it might have unintended side-effects anyway).

Comment: DId you seriously just say that "margin-top:100%' is calculated relative to WIDTH instead of HEIGHT?  WTFF.

Comment: @Triynko: Yes, this is counter-intuitive but that's what the standard says.